# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'txt' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Here is my program thus far.  When I run it, I receive the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'txt' referenced before assignment".  I tried adding global before txt to declare it as a global variable, but I get another error when I do that.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
def getwords():
    #function to get words in the input file
    try:
        global txt
        txt=open("sample.txt",'r')
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to open file')

    words=[]

    #read the file line by line
    for line in txt:
        #convert each line into words with space as delimiter
        words=words+line.split()

    return words

def wordcount(wordlist):
    #function to count words in the file
    #worddic is dictionary to store words frequency
    worddic=dict()

    for x in wordlist:
        #convert word to lowercase to ignorecase
        t=x.lower()
        if(t not in worddic):
            worddic[t]=0

        worddic[t]=worddic[t]+1

    max=-1
    t=''

    for x in worddic:
        if(worddic[x]>max):
            max=worddic[x]
            t=x

    return t

def letters(wordlist,lettercount):
    #function to count letters in the file
    for x in wordlist:
        #For each word in the list
        t=x.lower()

        for y in t:
            #for each letter in the word
            if(not (y in lettercount)):
                #if the letter is not in dictionary add it
                #and set frequency to zero
                lettercount[y]=0

            #increment the frequency of letter in dictionary
            lettercount[y] = lettercount[y]+1

def createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword):
    #creates an empty file 'statistics.txt'
    try:
        txt2=open("statistics.txt",'w+')
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to create file')

    txt2.write('Number of words in the file are '+str(len(wordlist))+'\n')
    txt2.write('Most repeated word in the file is '+mostword+'\n')

    for x in lettercount:
        #write to the file 'statistics.txt'
        txt2.write(x+' appeared in the file for '+str(lettercount[x])+' times \n')

def main():
    wordlist=getwords()

    #lettercount is a dictionary with letters as keys
    #and their frequency in the input file as data

    lettercount=dict()
    mostword=wordcount(wordlist)
    letters(wordlist,lettercount)
    createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword)

main()
```

Comment: What is the error you get when declaring it as global?

Answer (score 0):

When the `open()` call fails, you swallow the exception:

```
try:
    global txt
    txt=open("sample.txt",'r')
except IOError:
    print('Unable to open file')
```

Now `txt` is *never assigned to*, because it is the `open()` call that fails here. Instead of continuing with the function, you should return at this point:

```
try:
    txt=open("sample.txt",'r')
except IOError:
    print('Unable to open file')
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to structure your exceptions like this:

```
try:
    # normal code here
except:
    # handle the exception
```

For example this code is wrong because it runs the code that could fail outside of the exception handler

```
def createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword):
    #creates an empty file 'statistics.txt'
    try:
        txt2=open("statistics.txt",'w+')
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to create file')

    txt2.write('Number of words in the file are '+str(len(wordlist))+'\n')
    txt2.write('Most repeated word in the file is '+mostword+'\n')
```

Moving the normal read into the exception handler would look like this

```
def createoutput(lettercount,wordlist,mostword):
    #creates an empty file 'statistics.txt'
    try:
        txt2=open("statistics.txt",'w+')
        txt2.write('Number of words in the file are '+str(len(wordlist))+'\n')
        txt2.write('Most repeated word in the file is '+mostword+'\n')
    except IOError:
        print('Unable to create file')
```

but you never closed the file.  Where do you put the close file command?  After you opened it obviously, but what happens if txt2.write throws an exception?  What if some other problem happens in there? You never close!

With files you will want to do this, so the file is closed when it leaves the scope

```
with open("statistics.txt", "w+") as statsfile:
    statsfile.write("Number of words ...
```

and of course, you put that in an exception handler

```
def getwords(filename="sample.txt"):
    words = []
    try:
        with open (filename, 'r') as txt:
            for line in txt:
                words = words + line.split()
    except IOError:
        print "unable to open file"
    return words
```